# I need to find the minimum and average age of students from the birth day

Tags: sql, ms-access, average, date

I have a table `'Students'` which contains the `'DateOfBirth'` of students. I need an `SQL statement` that I can use in a query to give me the `average` and `minimum ages` as fields with those names?I don't want to have to add an age field I just want a SQL statement I can copy and paste that will return me what I need.

```
 SELECT MIN(DateOfBirth) AS Min Age, AVG(DateOfBirth) AS Avg Age FROM Students;
```

At the moment all the suggestions I have found ask me to specify a value when I run and I have no idea why?

Comment: GROUP BY, and the aggregate functions AVG and MIN!

Comment: Could you write this out for me as I am completly new to databases. I can get the min working but the avg doesn't work. it gives a number like16539.02 thanks

Comment: Sorry, you need to make some effort at least. (How will you else learn?) If you come up with something that doesn't work, add it to your question and I'm sure you can get some more hints.

Comment: SELECT MIN(DateOfBirth) AS Min Age, AVG(DateOfBirth) AS Avg Age
FROM Students;      This is what im using, but like i say the average is giving an age in the thousands

Comment: 'DateOfBirth'  is not age.. so ofc only aggregate functions will not work

Comment: No idea what an aggregate function is?! if you mean a number, then yes i know thats why i asked the question. I need a statement that will take the students date of births and calculate all of there ages and then find the average and minimum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first calculate age from `date of birth` then find average of age

```
Select AVG(Datediff("yyyy",DateOfBirth,getdate())) as AVGage from Students
Select MIN(Datediff("yyyy",DateOfBirth,getdate())) as MINage from Students
```

you can also calucate avg,min in one query

```
 Select AVG(Datediff("yyyy",DateOfBirth,getdate())) as AVGage , 
        MIN(Datediff("yyyy",DateOfBirth,getdate())) as MINage
        from Students
```

**FOR MS ACCESS DB:**

- Now() provides date and time
- Date() provides the date
- Time() provides the time

You can Use Date() Function

```
 Select AVG(Datediff("yyyy",DateOfBirth,DATE())) as AVGage , 
        MIN(Datediff("yyyy",DateOfBirth,DATE())) as MINage
        from Students
```

**Here is [SQLFIDDLE FOR SQLSERVER:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9c50f/1)**

Comment: getdate isnt being recognised

Comment: @jamesphillips See me edited answer .. you can use `Date()` function instead of `getdate()` if you are using ms access db

Comment: This works but asks me to specify a value when i run it! Why doesnt it just give me the table?

Comment: @jamesphillips i don't understand what value you specified during execution.? and what do you mean by `Why doesnt it just give me the table` ? please explain

Comment: As in I copy and paste your statement into the query then run the query. On running the query I am presented with a box that says 'specify parameter value'. Every other query i have run just pops open a table presenting me with the data ive asked for. Thats what i want from this. I just need the table to pop up with two fields. average age and minimum age with the calculated ages below them

Comment: do you have dob column in your table ?if not then replace dob from query to your column name

Comment: Yet again yes i do have a DateOfBirth column. Its the statement not my table thats the problem as ive run several quiries on it already. Its just the average age i cant calculate as every suggestion pops up these specify value boxes.

Comment: CREATE TABLE Students
(StudentID CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
FullName VARCHAR(50),
DepartmentCode CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
DateOfBirth DATE NOT NULL,
Gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
CountryOfBirth VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL); this is how ive made my table and its worked up till now

Comment: @jamesphillips did you replace `dob` from  `DateOfBirth` in sql statement ? after replace i think it should work ?

Comment: yeah, but I get the specify value pop ups still. It litterally just doesnt like the YY

Comment: @jamesphillips i have update my answer . 
`Select AVG(Datediff("yyyy",DateOfBirth,DATE())) as AVGage , 
        MIN(Datediff("yyyy",DateOfBirth,DATE())) as MINage
        from Students`

Comment: just replace yy from "yyyy"

Comment: Dear sweet god it worked! Thank you for sticking with me, have a pint on me :)

Comment: @jamesphillips accept my answer and vote it up if it is useful

Comment: `DateDiff("yyyy",#2014-12-31#,DATE())` returns 1 with today's `Date()`.  Is that how you want "age" calculated?

Comment: Lastly could I integrate this into a statement (Datediff("yyyy",DateOfBirth,DATE())) as Age                                                          into                                                                                                  Select FullName, DateOfBirth, CountryOfBirth
FROM Students
WHERE Gender = F                                                                              so that the date of birth is stated as an age?

Comment: Yes here is =>`Select FullName, DateOfBirth,Datediff("yyyy",DateOfBirth,DATE()) as Age, CountryOfBirth
 FROM Students WHERE Gender = F`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Students
GROUP BY DateOfBirth
ORDER BY DateOfBirth DESC


SELECT MIN(DateOfBirth) AS MinAges
FROM Students


SELECT AVG(DateOfBirth) AS AverageAges
FROM Students
```

Comment: When using this it says there is an error in the order by clause and it highlights the first select

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregate functions AVG and MIN.. you can easily google it btw ...To count the age you can use getDate function and count the age - depends on your format of column DateOfBirth ..

```
  select AVG((getDate()-DateOfBirth)/365) as avgAge , 
   MIN ((getDate()-DateOfBirth)/365) as minAge 
  from Students
```

Comment: Maybe you should specify which dbms it is? (Since getDate() is product specific.)

Comment: I get a pop up saying 'undefined function getgate' when using this. how do i get past this?

Comment: ok so thats as jarlh said, what dbms are u using? this is for ssql

Comment: im using Access SQL. And my dates of birth are in short date format.

Answer (score 0):

what i used is

```
 select avg(timestampdiff(year,NewDob,current_date())) as AvgAge
 from student
 where class like"%1%";
```

as age is not given in the table so i have to find the age of student as well and then do the average  even the average has to be done in particular class.

Comment: Please make it explicit that this is actually an answer and not a new question (which should otherwise be deleted)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).